# How to return a value of Set() on javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, set

I'm trying to find a set of 4 consecutively in row out of 7.
I divided the array of 7 to 4 options.
I'm using Set() method to find out if one of the sets has the value of 1 and return it's value plus a message.

````
function checkWinner(array){
  var set_1 = new Set(array.slice(0, 4));
  var set_2 = new Set(array.slice(1, 5));
  var set_3 = new Set(array.slice(2, 6));
  var set_4 = new Set(array.slice(3, 7));
 
  var sets = [set_1, set_2, set_3, set_4];
  for (var i = 0; i < sets.length; i++){
    if (sets[i].size === 1){
      // trying to return the set's only value + a message 'Wins!'
      // **return sets[i][0] --> that did'nt work**
    }
  }
  return 'Draw!'
}

let blackWinner = checkWinner(['black', 'red', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'red']);
console.log(blackWinner); //-> 'Black Wins!'```
````

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`set.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/values) to get the set's [iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators), call `.next()` to get the first element, and get its `value`.

```
return sets[i].values().next().value + " wins!";
```

```js
function checkWinner(array){
  var set_1 = new Set(array.slice(0, 4));
  var set_2 = new Set(array.slice(1, 5));
  var set_3 = new Set(array.slice(2, 6));
  var set_4 = new Set(array.slice(3, 7));
 
  var sets = [set_1, set_2, set_3, set_4];
  for (var i = 0; i < sets.length; i++){
    if (sets[i].size === 1){
      return sets[i].values().next().value + " wins!";
    }
  }
  return 'Draw!'
}

let blackWinner = checkWinner(['black', 'red', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'red']);
console.log(blackWinner);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the generator for values, call `next` and get the value.

````js
function checkWinner(array){
  var set_1 = new Set(array.slice(0, 4));
  var set_2 = new Set(array.slice(1, 5));
  var set_3 = new Set(array.slice(2, 6));
  var set_4 = new Set(array.slice(3, 7));
 
  var sets = [set_1, set_2, set_3, set_4];
  for (var i = 0; i < sets.length; i++){
    if (sets[i].size === 1){
      
      return sets[i].values().next().value;
    }
  }
  return 'Draw!'
}

let blackWinner = checkWinner(['black', 'red', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'red']);
console.log(blackWinner); //-> 'Black Wins!'```
````